# Jquery UI sortable in the table applied only in the 2nd and 3rd td

Tags: jquery, html-table, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a table look like this.

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>cell 1-1</td>
        <td>cell 1-2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>cell 2-1</td>
        <td>cell 2-2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>cell 3-1</td>
        <td>cell 3-2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>cell 4-1</td>
        <td>cell 4-2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>cell 5-1</td>
        <td>cell 5-2</td>
    </tr>  
<tbody>    
</table>
```

Now I want to sort this table row with jQuery ui where only 2nd and 3rd **td** will be sorted together and no effect or sort will be applied in the index.

```
<script>
   $( function() {
   $( "tbody" ).sortable({
       connectWith: "tr"
       }).disableSelection();
   } );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/NayanaDas/9wtn4z1c/
 .
Here only 2nd and 3rd columns will be sorted together, with the help of 2 tables and set sortable to the second table, try the below code:

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Index</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>2</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>column1</th>
                        <th>column2</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="sortTable">
                    <tr>
                        <td>cell 1-1</td>
                        <td>cell 1-2</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>cell 2-1</td>
                        <td>cell 2-2</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$( function() {
   $('#sortTable').sortable();
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry, i think i didn't make clear about my problem. i want every tr will be sortable but index will fix in it's position.

Comment: @user6690969 : please check the updated answer. Hope this works for you.

Comment: is it possible without using nested table??

Comment: I don't think so it is possible. Anyway will try.